# In Knight Rider 1982 TV series, did KITT have seat belts?

Tags: knight-rider

In *Knight Rider*, the 1982 TV series, did KITT have seat belts? I don't recall to ever seeing them. Michael never fastened, did he? Sport belts in the pilot "Knight of the Phoenix" don't count.

Comment: Does the "Passive Laser Restraint System" introduced in Season 3 count?
 - http://knight-rider.wikia.com/wiki/Passive_Laser_Restraint_System  - otherwise, seems like 'no'

Comment: http://knightrideronline.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7631

Comment: @NKCampbell, OK, but could you please write a separate answer?

Answer (score 3):

KITT evidently had lap belts for the front seats (or at least the front passenger seat), although not the shoulder belts that were standard in the 1980s.  This can be seen in "[The Final Verdict](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4lvsgn)" (season 1, episode 11).  Here is the teaser, in which the relevant scene appears.

Michael is shown trying to get his nebbish passenger's lap belt fastened.  The belt itself is not in view, but it is clear that it is there.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly revealed in the second episode (part 2 of the pilot) that KITT has front seat belts, apparently with shoulder straps, not just lap belts:

Note the restraints visible in the front passenger seat, and Michael's admonition to Buddy:

> "Now get in that seat right now and strap yourself down!"

It seems safe to conclude that there aren't any rear seat belts, or Michael would've told Buddy to buckle up in back instead of having him crawl into the front.

Comment: Now that I'm halfway through season 2, I can say that seat belt use in K.I.T.T. is unfortunately quite a rare thing.

Answer (score 1):

In season 3, traditional seatbelts became irrelevant with the introduction of KITT's Passive Laser Restraint System, which utilized a series of non-harmful lasers that would cover a portion of the occupant's body to prevent jarring in the event of sudden turns and stops.

Though it was never mentioned exactly as such, it's speculated that the PLRS was an extremely early version of what's come to be used in Sci-fi starships such as the *Enterprise* in *Star Trek*'s "Inertial Dampeners" technology, which requires NO physical restraints to reduce the effects of G forces.

It's how the *Enterprise* and other starships could accelerate to full impulse or warp speeds without leaving the crew splattered against the bulkheads.

Comment: But what about in the first two seasons? Did KITT have traditional seatbelts back then? Also, the bit about Star Trek doesn't really seem relevant to the question.

Comment: The bit about Star Trek is an example of what the passive laser restraint system actually is by comparing it to a related technology.

Comment: The most likely answer since there isn't one indicated on the show itself.  Front seat driver and passenger seatbelts were not required by law until 1983. The show originally aired in 1982, so it's likely the writers and directors didn't feel the need to include them visually in any of the storylines. "Although the Laser Restraint System was some sort of precursor to inertial dampening fields, it was never described as such. The Passive Laser Restraint System was introduced at the beginning of Season 3 to promote safe driving by reminding kids to wear their seat belts." -Knight Rider Wiki